# Projecting vector (3a) onto vector (-2b)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

The problem: Given two vectors, $a$ and $b$, where $\text{proj}_{{b}} {a} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -7 \end{pmatrix}$, find the value of $\text{proj}_{-2 {b}} (3 {a})$.

I'm not sure what to do to solve this problem other than use the formula $$\text{proj}_{{b}} {a} = \frac{a * b} {||b||^2} * b$$. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Using the vector relation you have, (the proj formula), you can express $proj_{-2b}(3a)$ in function of $proj_{b}(a)$! so, $proj_{-2b}(3a)=\frac{3a \star-2b}{\Vert -2b\Vert^{2}}(-2b)=3 proj_{b}(a)$, if I m not mistaken!

Answer (score 0):

projection depends only on the direction of $b$ not the size and is linear with respect to the projected vector. so in your problem $$proj_{-2b}(3a) = 3 \times proj_{b}(a)= 3 \times \pmatrix{4\\-7}=\pmatrix{12\\-21}. $$